# How to prove that if $S: U\rightarrow V$ and $T: V\rightarrow W$ are isomorphisms, then $TS$ is also an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

So if $S$ and $T$ are isomorphisms, then there exists $T^{-1}$ and $S^{-1}$, and then there exists $T^{-1}: W\rightarrow V$ and $S^{-1}: V\rightarrow U$, and so there exists $S^{-1} T^{-1}= (TS)^{-1}$. Could someone fix my proof?

Comment: You're practically there, $TS$ is an isomorphism if it has an inverse which is also a linear transformation. You've found an inverse, now just check it is also a linear map, which might be immediate based on the facts you have at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to work with the definition of an isomorphism being one-to-one and onto.

Let's prove that $TS$ is one-to-one.

Let $u_{1}$,$u_{2}\in U$. Suppose that

$$
TS(u_{1}) = TS(u_{2})\\
T(S(u_{1}) = T(S(u_{2})
$$
Bu by definition T is one-to-one (isomorphism). Then:
$$
S(u_{1}) = S(u_{2})
$$ 
But S is also an isomorphism $\implies$ $S$ is one-to-one, thus:
$$
u_{1} = u_{2}
$$
We can finally conclude that $TS$ is one-to-one.

Try using the same thought to prove that $TS$ is onto. Also, linearity of $TS$ is not difficult.